# Problem with git on windows ... pushes don't complete/timeout

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

Git works fine on my dev box, but ever so often, I'll go to push something to the repository and it will go through the motions like its actually pushing, but then it will get stuck like this

$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 544 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
...
...

It will just sit here for a couple of minutes then spit out this error.

Read from remote host xxxx.com: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Restarting my computer or coming back and trying it hours later usually works.
It really ruins my workflow though.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection reset by peer` means that the connection to the other side unexpectedly died.

There is a network problem between your computer and `example.com` or the GIT server is unstable for some reason. Check the logs and try to ping the server.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the idea.
The repo is hosted with unfuddle ... so I started pinging them from all my different servers, and it'd work on some but not on others. I figured out that I was getting different ips everytime, and that some servers wouldn't respond to pings and other would. So each time it hangs, I just kill and redo till it works ... I'm going to point my hosts file at one ip and that should fix it. THANKS!!!!